# Bind multiple events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I tried the following to change a span to red on `mouseover` and black on `mouseout`:

```
<span onmouseover="this.style.color='red' onmouseout=this.style.color='black'">Mouse over me!</span>
```

but it does not work!

How can I bind more than one event to a single element using JavaScript?

Comment: You are not closing your double quotes. Try this: <span onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Mouse over me!</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot Quote..

```html
<span onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Mouse over me!</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot quotes.

```
<span onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Mouse over me!</span>
                                         ^            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the `onmouseout` into `onmouseover` event, it is not correct.

**Try this:**

```
<span onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Mouse over me!</span>
```